# SSRS Expression 3 years prior to today's date

Tags: date, reporting-services, expression

Does anyone know of an expression for reporting services to return the first day of 3 years ago?

Example: Today's Date = 3/20/2018
Return date: 1/1/2015

I would like to always return 1/1/2015 regardless of what date it is during the current year.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the best way to go about it.. but a hack way would be to do this in SSRS is :

```
=CDate("1/1/" & Str(Year(Today())-3))
```

This is assuming you always want 3 years ago of course.. adjust to suit

Answer (score 0):

```
=dateadd(dateinterval.year, -3, DateAdd("d", -1, Today))
```

This will give you date 3 year exactly from yesterday.

If you want today and then 3 year back then change it to

```
=dateadd(dateinterval.year, -3, Today)
```